# http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content

Tags: html

I should have IE 8 document mode in ie8.

and ie 9 document mode in ie 9

for this what should I do for this?

Note:My Doc type is `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything.

Comment: As far as I understand, you do not need it at all. You may need it once you want ie9 in ie8 or ie7 mode, but if you want ie8 in ie8 mode and ie9 in ie9 - you will get that by default.

Comment: What about Compatibility Mode? Most IT depts force this for Intranet sites on client machines. "Edge" rendering is the only way to bypass this.

Comment: what is the meaning of content="IE=7,IE=8,IE=edge"?

Answer (score 3):

You want Internet Explorer to render using it's most up-to-date rendering engine? If so, this will do it:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

The above tag should be included in the `<head>` section of your web page. Internet Explorer will use this "X-UA-Compatible" flag to determine which rendering mode to use. By specifying "edge"-rendering, you are instructing IE to use it's most up-to-date engine. For further information on this topic, check out this resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_mode_(browser)#Internet_Explorer

I should add that this is the default behaviour unless the user's browser is set to run in Compatibility mode by default.

Comment: what is the meaning of content="IE=7,IE=8,IE=edge"?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I could've made that clearer. Will edit the above, hopefully it will answer your question better.